# Show items from a specific document library within search result page

Tags: sharepoint-search

I have created the Search Service Application and my Search is working fine. But my current requirement is I need to search for documents within a specific Document Library. Currently my search result page shows all the results from the whole site. My requirement is to show a documents from a single document library. How can I achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a search scope and give URL for your specific document library only in the rule.

For details please check this link.

[Help Link](http://www.bentedder.com/create-a-search-scope-for-a-sharepoint-2010-list-or-library/)

**Update:** For SharePoint 2013 you need to create a Results Source and configure query to search in particular library only and configure your Search Results WebPart to use your Results Source.

Please check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013office-365-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx) link

Comment: Thanks Varun. But I am using Sharepoint 2013. So is there anything for Sharepoint 2013 for a specific document library.

Comment: See my Updated Answer

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query

Answer (score 13):

In addition to creating a result source (search scope), you can also simply provide the relevant query text directly in the search result web part of your search page.  (See below).

NOTE:  Be sure to include quotation marks around the URL path, I could not get it work otherwise.

```
{searchboxquery} path:"https://siteURL.com/DocumentLibraryName/*"
```

For multiple locations, simply add them with a space delimiter.

```
{searchboxquery} path:"https://siteURL.com/DocumentLibrary1/*" path:"https://siteURL/DocumentLibrary2/*" path:"https://siteURL/DocumentLibrary2/*"
```

[image]

Comment: This is a much better answer

Comment: Can we query for specific folder in a Document Library ??