# Content search web part

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there a way to display all the pages from "Site Pages" library using content search web part? And is it possible to include 3 level hierarchy on top navigation without changing the master page?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to display all the pages from "Site Pages" library
>   using content search web part?

Yes, if they have been crawled by Search. [You can find the steps on how to do so here.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/110965/2536)

> is it possible to include 3 level hierarchy on top navigation without
>   changing the master page?

Yes, through powershell. [You can find the steps on how to do so here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/fb90034c-76f5-4cc5-9e73-7e4783f8c779/powershell-script-to-add-hierarchy-in-global-navigation)